# Does working while you are studying affect your GPA?

Tags: job, gpa, tuition

I am studying computer science and I have money to pay for my university study, but I do not have money to spend on entertainment such as going to cinema with my friends in the weekend or upgrading my laptop. I have applied for a job at McDonald's. My shift is 4 days per week with 7 hours per day.

I am scared this would affect my grades. How can I balance my studies with the part-time work I must do in order to improve my living standards or afford a social life?

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone who doesn't know you well can offer you useful personal advice.  Some people are able to successfully balance school and work, others are not, and it depends greatly on other circumstances (course load, other responsibilities, etc).  If you are looking for statistics about how outside employment tends to affect grades, that might be an appropriate question for this site, but of course it wouldn't necessarily help you personally.  Personally, 28 hours a week seems like a lot to balance with school, but again I don't know you or your situation.

Comment: This question is pretty badly formulated; I am sure you would find examples that indicate both ends of the scale. Just exactly how working might effect *your* GPA is impossible for us to estimate. Essentially how bad it is to work while studying is a very subjective question.

Comment: With a full-time computer science degree and 27 hours of work there will probably not enough time for you to rest or go the movies. Is there any other part-time job alternative (e.g. tutoring / freelance programming) that will take less of your time? Also working on McDonalds can be quite stressful and exhausting.

Comment: Similar to @Alexandros, try to get a job which relates to computer science. McD offers no benefits other than money.

Comment: Maybe look into options like short-term work at the holidays or over the summer. Stores often need extra staff around Christmas, for example. Or you might find a job that allows you to do some studying during downtime. (E.g., a shop or restaurant with slow periods, or working as a security guard where you have to do regular rounds, but in-between you can do other things as long as you keep your eye on the monitors). Not every employer will agree to this, of course, but you may get lucky and find one that does.

Answer (score 5):

[This study](http://www.nber.org/papers/w1742.pdf) suggests that employment outside the university (especially in excess of 25 hours per week) does have a negligible adverse effect on GPA, and a signigicant adverse effect on the probability of a student's continues enrollment. A second paper ([here](http://www.nber.org/papers/w14006.pdf))  suggests that hours worked **do** have a significant negative effect on student grades.

> ...results show that an additional weekly work hour reduces current year GPA
>   by about 0.011 points...

A personal anecdote: When I attended the mandatory freshman orientation seminar during my first semester as an undergrad, they recommended *no more than fifteen hours per week*, suggesting that anything more than that would tend to have a negative impact on our grades. I do not now recall whether they also provided references to back up their claims...

Of course, this is a general guideline, and an individual student may well be able to handle more. I know some students who were somehow able to juggle a full course load, a full-time job, AND major family responsibility, but those paragons are very rare!

Comment: I worked 40-50 hours per week and studied full-time. I had nothing left for anything else (certainly not a family). I found working helped with my studies mainly because I was studying business (so the work gave my something to apply theories to in real life).

Answer (score 0):

I worked full time for the first year and a half and part time for the remaining year and a half during my undergraduate career for Computer Science. It certainly meant that I had less time and flexibility but, ultimately, I think it made me more marketable and a bit better prepared for the working world than many of my peers. That's being said there's a fundamental difference between my work and your work - my work was within the realm of Computer Science.

Having a job, any job, is a necessity for many students. I would recommend, though, trying to find a job that's going to benefit, even if in a small way, your studies. Many schools have IT departments that hire undergraduate students as part time help. Many schools have departments that have an independent IT department, separate from the main IT department. Research schools tend to have infrastructure related jobs and internships. University towns often have businesses that are happy to have future CS graduates working in their IT or programming departments. If you have been in school for a bit you should know some of your professors - there are often paid jobs in research labs all over campuses. They aren't advertised but good relationships with professors will open a lot of doors.

I would try to get a job that's going to have long term benefit for you. Having a high level of confidence and comfort around IT business practices makes you a far more marketable computer scientist than someone who can code but is afraid to install an operating system(for example). Knowing the vocab and jargon will make you more marketable. Having a job, of any sort, with references will help when it comes time to start looking at what happens after you graduate.

As to whether a part time job will effect your grades... it will at least a little. Instead of spending 40 hours on some projects, sometimes I only had the time and energy, a finite resource to be sure, to spend 30 hours. I ended up graduating with a very good GPA(honestly I think being involved in research affected my GPA more than my job.) But having a job, especially a challenging job, in addition to being in school will mean you will have to be more organized than many of your peers. It means you'll have to be on top of your school work and that last minute all nighters will be pretty detrimental.

I don't think there's an all-inclusive answer for whether people should work during school. In my own hiring and looking-to-be-hired experience students who are employed during their schooling tend to be more reliable, more marketable and a more 'sure thing' than their counterparts who did not. But, as mentioned by J. Zimmerman in their excellent answer there are sacrifices involved. As a CS student I would be putting a lot of effort in moving beyond a 'mcjob' and into something at least slightly relevant.